2024 . Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
I encountered the following error after integrating the Firebase library:
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
..ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

my Podfile platform version -> platform :ios, '12.0'
I am downloading the Firebase SDK using the following in my Podfile:
pod 'FirebaseFirestore',
:git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git',
:tag => '11.0.0'
What I’ve tried so far:
I deleted the Podfile.lock and re-ran pod install.
I ran flutter clean and flutter pub get.
I made sure the iOS deployment target is set correctly in the Podfile (e.g., platform :ios, '12.0').
I confirmed that all Firebase dependencies are included in the pubspec.yaml.
None of these steps resolved the issue. How can I fix this?
I expected the Firebase Firestore module to be correctly integrated and the project to build successfully in Xcode.
